# JQueryMobile Issue with adding ScrollView to Dynamic Data

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having issues with the JqueryMobile Scroll View:

Here is the code below:

```
   function scroll_Info(json){
         var scroll_Info = document.getElementById("scroll_Info");

    var dt =json.results; 
      if (dt.length <= 0){
       }

          else{         
             $('#scroll_Info').append('<ul data-scroll="x" class="double-block-view-h">');
             $('#scroll_Info').append('<ul class="view">');

      scrollview = $('#scroll_Info');

          for (var i=0; i<dt.length; i++){

        scroll_Info.innerHTML +=  "<ul align='left'><ul data-scroll='x' class='double-block-view-h'><li class='square'>1</li></ul>";
        }
 $("#scroll_Info").scrollview();

       }
    }
```

I am displaying this info in the ul:

```
 <ul id="scroll_Info"></ul>
```

But it is not displaying correctly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to add an exclamation mark in your selector? `$("#scroll_Info!")`

Comment: Hey Jasper didn't mean to add that here, typo. When I change revert "scrollview" to "listview" it displays the information correctly. Any idea why?